# AWS Cognito Login using username and password in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create an Android app login using AWS cognito.

I am able to register users and them to user pools but I am unable to log them in.

I refered to this link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-user-sign-in-android) to register my client and it works flawlessly.

I have tried this link(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html#set-up-email-and-password) as well but I want to use my own UI to login users.

Also if someone could help me out on how to keep the user logged in when he runs the app next time. That would be great too.

Comment: You can use this sample as a reference for implementing your own UI: 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

Comment: I tried refering to that but couldn't understand what was going on...
Do you have some other references ?